# If I have an application registered with Azure AD, how do i leverage the Schools REST API?

Tags: azure-active-directory

If I have an application registered with Azure AD, how do i best leverage the Schools REST API?

I think there are a few things i can't reconcile within the docs, so bear with me. Specifically, is there a permission level that allows me to request data from this rest endpoint? At the moment i'm requesting basic permissions (User.Read) but it seems according to the [school data sync](https://sds.microsoft.com/) that a district has to register and share their SIS information. This leads me to believe that a user cannot grant any such permission, and instead the application has to be granted the permission by the 'district'.

- If a district finds my app in the azure marketplace do they grant permission or can i have a situation where they are using the app found in the azure marketplace but haven't granted sds permission?

Also, can the 'id' from https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me be used to query the schools rest API? How do i query student/teacher information about the currently signed in user? Reading the docs it seems as i have to traverse a tree of schools, to school, to students, to a specific student.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems to me that when a district shares their SIS information, their data is synced to the Azure AD in Office 365. There are a lot of extension attributes that contain school, teacher, and student information (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/education-rest-attributes), but otherwise it seems that you query the graph API in a pretty standard fashion.

Comment: I think you're right that the SIS information is synced from an Office Edu tenant using school data sync, and that the information is then made available using the API. My question is about when/how permissions are granted to an app, how transferable graph identifiers are (is a new one created from SIS information?), and pitfalls perhaps in what looks to be an asynchronous process (could be wrong). I don't think this is a standard approach because a lot of it looks like it's out of the developers hands.